# GitLab: You cannot push commits for . You can only push commits that were committed with one of your own verified emails

Tags: git, gitlab

I am having this weird issue where I cloned a repository with my credentials (`my_correct@email.adress`). But I can not push the changes because I always receive this message:

```
GitLab: You cannot push commits for 'my_wrong@email.adress' . You can only push commits that were committed with one of your own verified emails.
```

The issue is that when I check the global and the repository users I find it is `my_correct@email.adress`:

Global (below confirms my correct address):

```
git config  --global user.email
git config  --global user.name
```

Repository (below confirms my correct address):

```
git config  user.email
git config   user.name
```

What should I do and what is the reason behind this mysterious mystery?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was able to fix the same issue using this git command:

`git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit`

I initially tried to commit with the wrong email but even after setting user.name and user.email in `git config --global` to the correct one, I kept getting the same "You cannot push commits for..." error above.

The solution was resetting the author in git - then the push was accepted to Gitlab.

For reference: https://github.com/git-tips/tips#revert-undo-a-commit-by-creating-a-new-commit

Comment: not working for me cause i have multiple commits

Answer (score 17):

In my case there was a committer restriction in project on GitLab.
"Users can only push commits to this repository that were committed with one of their own verified emails." Since I configured SSH also with my machine, so my user email was updated in git global file with my machine's address, hence remote was not allowing to PUSH.

You can find this at- gitlab-> settings -> Repository -> Push Rules ; just  disable this commit restriction and it will work.

Answer (score 7):

`git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit` only changes author in the last commit, if you have multiple commits, you still won't able to push.

Check it with `git log`, and reset every commit with the improper author and commit again.

Comment: AFAIK *reverting* does not remove the commits from your local branch, i.e. you will still be pushing someone else's commits... maybe you meant resetting the branch BEFORE that unwanted commit, then applying a patch with all the commits you want

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant _reset_, not _revert_! I've edited it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ask an administrator *for the repo you cloned your project from* to remove the committer restrictions from the push rules on *your* repo. See [Enabling push rules][1][https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html#enabling-push-rules].

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the pushing restrictions so that you don't need to go through all the commits and change the email.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the solution here because all of my .gitconfig's have the correct and authorized emails to push to upstream. In my team, I've found out a logical solution for this, and the reason we can't find the correct solution seems like because of gitlab's misleading error message. The problem is not about our current commit's author in general. We encounter cases where a branch deleted in the origin couldn't be updated in local. So the solution that worked for me and many of my colleagues is below:

```
git remote update origin --prune
```